# Is there a way to get comma separated values of a column regardless of group_concat_max_len size?

Tags: mysql

I need to get the contents of a column as a comma-separated list.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column) FROM table;
```

does the job but the table is very large and the default value for

```
group_concat_max_len is 1024.


SET GLOBAL  group_concat_max_len = 999999;
```

I tried that to increase the size but it is not allowed because the app is running on a shared server and I don't have the privilege. What else can I try, please?

Comment: Can you use any scripting language (Php, Perl, javascript, java, c# ...) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the group_concat_max_len per session instead. You will have the rights for that.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 999999;
```

- read more about it in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This works well on localhost but after running the statement on the server, the result is still the same.

Comment: What do you mean with "the same". There's actually no way (I know of) to deny the right to do this. What version exactly is running on the server?

Comment: When I execute the statement, it's successful but the result is still limited. The PHPMyAdmin version on the server is 4.7.3, Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73, PHP version: 5.6.30. I only get the desired result when I execute it in localhost.

Comment: Try it in the official mysql command line client. Other frontends I don't trust one bit. When it works there, file a bug for phpmyadmin or whereever it's not working. And when your client is 5.1, your server is also 5.1 I assume? If so, don't you think it's time to update? This is not a supported version anymore. 5.5 is not supported. 5.6 came out in 2011!